# cant get data From data-n in element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `Span` :

```
<span class="span-link" id="2" data-state="True" onclick="javascript: changestate(this.id);">Change State</span>
```

and in Javascript function I use this code for get value :

```
function changestate(_thingid) {
    alert(_thingid);
    var tt = $(this).attr("data-state");
    alert(tt);        
}
```

I getting `undefinded` for `data-state` . I test by `$(this).data("state")`
and so getting `undefined` too .

whats a problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing id, not the object, so change it to this:

```
var tt = $('#'+_thingid).attr("data-state");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ne5b8zm/

Comment: Its return `Undefined`

Comment: sorry , Its cached on my browser . thnaks

Answer (score 2):

That's because `this` in that context refers to the `window` object that doesn't have any attribute. You should pass the element to your handler and use it instead of the `this` keyword.

```
... onclick="changestate(this);"
```

```
function changestate(thing) {
    var id = thing.id;
    var tt = $(thing).attr("data-state");
    alert(tt);
}
```

Another option is using the passed id for selecting the clicked element which is not a good idea in this case as `this` already refers to the clicked element.

Since you are using jQuery you could also use it's `on` method. `this` keyword in the `on` callback refers to clicked element.

```
$('span.span-link').on('click', function() {
     var id = this.id;
     var tt = $(this).data('data-state');
});
```